# Hang with 5 Red Dots after installing AMD Propetiary Driver

Tags: drivers, ati, 14.10

I've tried installing a new propetiary driver, and after reboot it hangs with 5 red dots on the screen.

I'm currently using an AMD R7 265 Graphics Card. I'm also running Ubuntu 14.10 Utopic Unicorn.

(Forgive me, I'm not much of a tech savvy and I cannot find a solution anywhere right now)

The driver that I've installed : http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDCatalyst14-9LINReleaseNotes.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have 1 or more conflicting drivers fighting each other.  You need to purge all old drivers from the system and install NEW driver using (Software & Updates) Additional drivers box.

Comment: And how could I purge all of my old drivers?
I struggled to get through the 5 red dots and now I'm back into ubuntu's desktop. Yet I can't switch back to my default driver.